# Count all sequences in a list

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

My self-learning task is to find how many sequences are on the list. A sequence is a group of numbers, where each is one 1 bigger than the previous one. So, in the list:

```
[1,2,3,5,8,10,12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,24,25,26]
```

there are 3 sequences:

- `1,2,3`
- `12,13,14,15`
- `23,24,25,26`

I've spent few hours and got a solution, which I think is a workaround rather than the real solution.

My solution is to have a separate list for adding sequences and count the attempts to update this list. I count the very first appending, and every new appending except for the sequence, which already exists.

I believe there is a solution without additional list, which allows to count the sequences itself rather than the list manipulation attempts.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,5,8,10,12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,24,25,26]

goods = []
count = 0

for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    if numbers[i] + 1 == numbers[i+1]:

        if goods == []:
            goods.append(numbers[i])
            count = count + 1

        elif numbers[i] != goods[-1]:
            goods.append(numbers[i])
            count = count + 1

        if numbers[i+1] != goods[-1]:
            goods.append(numbers[i+1])
```

The output from my debugging:

```
Number 1 added to: [1]
First count change: 1

Number 12 added to: [1, 2, 3, 12]
Normal count change: 2

Number 23 added to: [1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 14, 15, 23]
Normal count change: 3
```

Comment: Hint: Why not try making `goods` (what's with this variable name?) contain a list of lists. E.g. for an input of `[1,2,3,5,8,10,12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,24,25,26]`, it will ultimately contain `[[1,2,3,5], [8], [10], [12,13,14,15], 17, 19, 21, [23,24,25,26]]`. From there, you can filter all lists of size 1, to get `[[1,2,3,5], [12,13,14,15], [23,24,25,26]]`, whose `len` is the `3` you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still not sure how to recognize when to start a new list. And if I only knew how to do it, I might find the way to avoid "goods" list at all.

P.S. "Goods" is a legacy word vs "Bads" when I tried to count the breaks in the sequences.

Comment: Well suppose you had a `result` list, whose elements were sublists, which we can call a `run`. You could have an active run (the one that you're currently working on), which you terminate when you notice the next element doesn't belong in it (e.g. it's not exactly one more than the last element of the active run). At this point, you add this run to your results, and you reset the active run into a new empty list, and continue on building it up until you find the next discontinuity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to iterate over pairwise elements:

```
l = [1,2,3,5,8,10,12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,24,25,26]

res = [[]]
for item1, item2 in zip(l, l[1:]):  # pairwise iteration
    if item2 - item1 == 1:
        # The difference is 1, if we're at the beginning of a sequence add both
        # to the result, otherwise just the second one (the first one is already
        # included because of the previous iteration).
        if not res[-1]:  # index -1 means "last element".
            res[-1].extend((item1, item2))
        else:
            res[-1].append(item2)
    elif res[-1]: 
        # The difference isn't 1 so add a new empty list in case it just ended a sequence.
        res.append([])

# In case "l" doesn't end with a "sequence" one needs to remove the trailing empty list.
if not res[-1]:
    del res[-1]

>>> res
[[1, 2, 3], [12, 13, 14, 15], [23, 24, 25, 26]]

>>> len(res)  # the amount of these sequences
3
```

---

A solution without `zip` only requires small changes (the loop and the the beginning of the loop) compared to the approach above:

```
l = [1,2,3,5,8,10,12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,24,25,26]

res = [[]]
for idx in range(1, len(l)):
    item1 = l[idx-1]
    item2 = l[idx]
    if item2 - item1 == 1:
        if not res[-1]:
            res[-1].extend((item1, item2))
        else:
            res[-1].append(item2)
    elif res[-1]: 
        res.append([])
if not res[-1]:
    del res[-1]
```

Comment: I would like to avoid zip() and write more code myself for learning. Thanks for the idea to use extend vs append. In the original code, I replaced the last appending by extending, The result I get is [[1], 2, 3, [12], 13, 14, 15, [23]]. How to make it look like in yours output?

Comment: @Sam You need to `append` to the last sublist `goods[-1].append(...)` (note the `-1`) to make it work. :(

Comment: @Sam The `zip` is just convenient here. It should also work if you iterate over the indices `for idx in range(1, len(l))` (instead of the `zip`) and index inside the loop `item1 = l[idx-1]` and `item2 = l[idx]`. :)

Comment: I'm so happy to find the solution myself few second before you wrote! I also needed to adjust syntax and to add a list not an element plus avoid duplication. I will update my post, and mark your answer as solution too.

Comment: I have updated my post, could you please take a look? I get the result I needed, but maybe I'm missing some check or condition which I don't see.

Comment: @Sam Instead of including an answer into the question you should self-answer the question. I will have a look then (just post another comment here). :)

Comment: Thanks, done. I can't accept it as answer so quickly as a new user, though.

Comment: @Sam Yes, there are some differences for self-answers (see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). But it looks correct and seems to handle all cases I tested with my function and I upvoted it. :)

Comment: Appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your help!

Legman suggested the original solution I failed to implemented before I end up with another solution in this post.

MSeifert helped to find a the right way with the lists:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,5,8,10,12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,24,25,26]
print("Numbers:", numbers)

goods = []
count = 0

for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    if numbers[i] + 1 == numbers[i+1]:
        if goods == []:
            goods.append([numbers[i]])
            count = count + 1
        elif numbers[i] != goods[-1][-1]:
            goods.append([numbers[i]])
            count = count + 1
        if numbers[i+1] != goods[-1]:
            goods[-1].extend([numbers[i+1]])

print("Sequences:", goods)
print("Number of sequences:", len(goods))
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from python *itertools documentation*, as demonstrated [here](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples) you can use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) and [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do that using only one list, like so:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26]
>>>
>>> counter = 0
>>> for k, g in groupby(enumerate(l), lambda (i,x):i-x):
...     seq = map(itemgetter(1), g)
...     if len(seq)>1:
...         print seq
...         counter+=1
...
[1, 2, 3]
[12, 13, 14, 15]
[23, 24, 25, 26]
>>> counter
3
```

**Notice:** As correctly mentioned by @MSeifert, tuple unpacking in the signature is only possible in Python 2 and it will fail on Python 3 - so this is a `python 2.x` solution.

Comment: Tuple unpacking in the signature is only possible in Python 2. It will fail on Python 3 (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`).

Comment: Although I would use a solution like this in the real world, it bypasses much of the point of an exercise like this

Comment: Thanks! It's good to learn about itertools. As Alexander mentioned, for this task I would like a more "hands-on" solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved with dynamic programming.  If you only want to know the number of sequences and don't actually need to know what the sequences are you should be able to do this with only a couple of variables.  Realistically, as you're going through the list you only really need to know if you are currently in a sequence, if not if the next one is incremented by 1 making this the beginning of a sequence and if so is the next one greater than 1 making it the exit of a sequence.  After that, you just need to make sure to end the loop one cell before the end of the list since the last cell cant form a sequence by itself and so that it doesn't cause an error when you're performing a check.  Below is example code

```
isSeq=false

for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    if isSeq==false:
       if numbers[i]+1==numbers[i+1]:
           isSeq=true  
           count=count+1
    elif 
       if numbers[i]+1!=numbers[i+1]:
           isSeq=false
```

Here is a link to a dynamic programming tutorial.

https://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-dynamic-programming

Comment: This is exactly what I had in my head at the start! I wasn't sure how to implement it, so I followed the wrong direction with that extra list... Although, I'm not sure how to solve the task with the lists yet, I'm happy with your suggestion.